# Program wont repaint

Tags: java, animation, repaint

I am trying to make a simple walking movement/animation, but it only displays the final step of the animation. Here is the code involved:

This is the class that tests for the keyPress events (not shown):

```
public class Game extends JFrame{ //Contains the game's panel
    public static MainPanel mp = new MainPanel();
    public static Player player = new Player();
    private int wait = 100;

    public Game(){
        //initialize everything
        getContentPane().add( mp );
    }

    private void Wait(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    private void up(){
        player.Up1();
        mp.Repaint();
        Wait();
        player.Up2();
        mp.Repaint();
        Wait();
        player.Up1();
        mp.Repaint();
        Wait();
        player.Up3();
        mp.Repaint();
        Wait();
        player.Up1();
        mp.Repaint();
    }
}
```

and this is the player class:

```
public class Player{
    public static BufferedImage pic=null;
    private static int characterNum;
    public Player(){
        //initializes player
        int characterNum;
    }

    public static void setChar( int character ){
        try {
            pic = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/character final/forwardsprite.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println ( "No boyDown image in Player" );
        }
        characterNum = character;
    }

    public static void Up1(){
        if( characterNum==1 ){
            try {
                pic = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/character final/backsprite.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 System.out.println ( "No boyDown image in Player" );
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Up2(){
        try {
            pic = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/character final/backspriteLeftstep.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println ( "No boyDown image in Player" );
        }
    }
    public static void Up3(){
        try {
            pic = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/character final/backspriteRightstep.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println ( "No boyDown image in Player" );
        }
    }
```

I believe the issue lies in the repainting of the MainPanel, but I have spent hours trying to solve the issue. I think I just need another set of eyes to look at it.

Comment: I see you're using `Thread.sleep`. Are you sleeping the event dispatch thread? If you do that, nothing will repaint

Comment: I just want to wait a bit of time before the next stage of the animation, so how do you propose I do so?

Comment: Then queue up the next change with a `Timer`. Or use another thread. If you sleep the event dispatch thread, the whole gui will sleep.